# Why is this app struggling to process?

Tags: wine, games

*First off: Merry Christmas everyone*

I am currently having issue with a map editing software that im running through Wine. I am unsure why it is struggling to process. every function of the editor im trying to use works great. but soon as I try to load the map to be edited for the software.... it lags and does not want to process. I am stuck wondering if im missing a component that is causing it to lag? or could it be my computer? to which I think.... No cause everything else other than this one editor runs fine.

To give examples of this I will post links to some of the software I use. links are supplied on the two items.

Editor: I suggest Zone Doctor on the [map editing](https://www.ff6hacking.com/wiki/doku.php?id=ff3:ff3us:util:start) list.

Rom: [Final Fantasy 3 rom](https://www.loveroms.com/download/super-nintendo/final-fantasy-3-v11-u-/5582) that I am trying to mod.

If anyone seems to suffer from this issue. Id greatly like to know how to resolve it otherwise my own personal project comes to a halt.